# Java Selenium find element (xpath)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

This is my first post in StackOverFlow, and being a chinese, please ignore my poor english lol.

I am trying to use selenium do following actions:
1.open the url(url in code)
2. click "zonal" link under the "Real-Time Market LBMP" menu, which has unique tag"P-24A"
3. get the time for "most recent interval" file and print out.

High lighted elements are my target:

[image]

I was stucked with second xpath selector:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/Haiqing/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver(); 

    wd.get("http://mis.nyiso.com/public/"); 
    wd.switchTo().frame("MENU");

    WebElement zonalElement = wd.findElement(By.name("P-24Alist"));
    zonalElement.click();

    wd.switchTo().defaultContent();
    wd.switchTo().frame("BODY");
    WebElement mostRecentIntervalTime = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Most recent interval')]/../following-sibling::td/span"));
    System.out.println("Most recent updated time is : " + mostRecentIntervalTime.getText()); 
    wd.quit();
```

And the HTML is belowed:
        
        
        Most recent interval
        
        
        12/04/16 06:42 EST

got exception [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1diY.png)

Comment: Create a minimal example and update your question (image description, remove bold)...

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I updated my question and now looks cleaner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is inside `<frame>`, you need to switch to it first.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("MENU");
```

And to switch back

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

You can look at the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html) for more options for `switchTo()` method.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129736/discussion-on-answer-by-guy-java-selenium-find-element-xpath).